# CI bonfire + can't view the module at public context

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

My Public contet URL is `http://localhost:8080/bonfire/`. I have created a blog module and checked **Public** in **Contexts Required** cheked list. I saw all the files have been created inside the module. I can only view the module in the admin section. If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/bonfire/blog` I will get 404 error. I already fixed my .htaccess base path **RewriteBase /bonfire/**. Please help me to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have followed well the tutorial:

http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/tut_blog

It won't be wrong.

If you already saw your Blog in the context menu at admin side (under: Content menu)
Please have a look again on above tutorial at "The Public Context"

You should have a class for front-end:

```
class Blog extends Front_Controller
```

If you do not see your Blog in the context menu at the admin side, it's likely you forget to run migration: **Developer / Database / Migrations**